# Calculating with variables in Unreal Engine 4 blueprints

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Assume I have 2 variables for player Strength and Agility. I want to use these 2 variables to calculate damage dealt to enemies based on a simple formula, which is Damage = Strength * 2 + Agility * 0.1

How would I go about creating this in blueprints?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the [math expression node](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/Blueprints/UserGuide/MathNode/)!

Answer (score 0):

In blueprint you would have to first do your calculation using the float multiplier node (to do Strength * 2 and Agility * 0.1). Then use the float additional node to add these two together and assign the result of the addition node to your Damage variable